# Alternative for Guidance Automation toolkit

Tags: c#, asp.net, guidance-automation-tool

I am trying to build a an application framework template where developers can use MVP pattern using Guidance Automation Toolkit. But i could see that in MSDN:

```
Guidance Automation
Retired Content 
This content is outdated and is no longer being maintained. It is provided as a courtesy for individuals who are still using these technologies.
This page may contain URLs that were valid when originally published, but now link to sites or pages that no longer exist.
```

So what is the alternative for achieving the same functionality in VS2010 and later version?

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this.  I'd look at NuGet package templates.  This will allow you to open a blank solution and then install the NuGet package to create the structure of your app.

If you get the NuGet [Package Explorer](http://nuget.codeplex.com/releases/view/59864) you can then inspect other NuGet packages.

Comment: What am trying to do is to provide an option to right click on any web application folder and menu with 'Add Page/User Control with Presenter which will create a page/or user control and neccessary classes(Model, IVIew, Presenter etc in same project or in another project) like in WCSF

Comment: Yes, you can do the same thing with a NuGet package, except you would right-click on references > Manage NuGet Packages, and then you could choose the package from a local folder or a network NuGet server  http://nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Server.

Comment: The NuGet.Server project is a good example, actually.  Here is a tutorial: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/31/hosting-simple-nuget-package-feed.aspx